# Java : switching between dll depends on system architecture (32/64)

Tags: java, dll, 32bit-64bit, switch-statement

I have a Java program uses some dlls. As these embeded dlls have to be built for a specific system architecture (32 or 64bits) I want to make a method/something that allow my program to switch between 32/64 bits version of dlls (or disable the library load if the program run on a 64 bits system)

I hope there is a solution different from making two versions of the program

Thanks in advance,
Damien

Answer (score 6):

Use system properties:

```
if ("x86".equals(System.getProperty("os.arch"))) {
   // 32 bit
} else if ("x64".equals(System.getProperty("os.arch"))) {
   // 64 bit
}
```

Comment: Okay, and what happens on my old PPC Mac?

Comment: Just make another if? I think that idea is rather clear, this is just a sample of code.

Comment: os.arch is amd64 on my machine

Answer (score 3):

You can use the System Property `sun.arch.data.model`

```
String dataModel = System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model");
if("32").equals(dataModel){
    // load 32-bit DLL
}else if("64").equals(dataModel){
    // load 64-bit DLL
}else{
    // error handling
}
```

Careful: this property is defined on Sun VMs only!

**Reference:**

- [Java HotSpot FAQ > When writing Java
  code, how do I distinguish between 32
  and 64-bit operation?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#64bit_detection)

Answer (score 2):

A brute force way is to run

```
boolean found = false;
for(String library: libraries)
    try {
        System.loadLibrary(library);
        found = true;
        break;
    } catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError ignored) {
    }
if(!found) throw new UnsatifiedLinkError("Could not load any of " + libraries);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using OSGi and JNI, you can specify the DLLs appropriate for different platforms and architectures in the manifest via Bundle-NativeCode.

For example:

```
    Bundle-NativeCode: libX.jnilib; osname=macOSX, X.dll;osname=win32;processor=x86
```

Comment: what about libraries having the same name? I have to import the rxtx library for both ARM and x86 architectures and the library is called librxtxSerial.so in both cases. How can i distinguish them using this header??

Comment: @marbal - I think you would list the library twice, once for `processor=86`, and once for `processor=ARM_le` (for little-endian) or `processor=ARM_be` (for big-endian). These values and others can be found in the table at http://www.osgi.org/Specifications/Reference#processor .

Comment: I've created a folder named "lib" and 2 subfolders called "x86" and "arm" and i've put in each of them the libraries built respectively for processors x86 and arm. Then, in the header, i've wrote this: `lib/x86/librxtxSerial.so; processor=x86, lib/arm/librxtxSerial.so; processor=ARM_le` but every time i get the same error: `No match found for native code: ` . What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: i've descriibed the problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32625924/osgi-bundle-nativecode-give-error-no-match-found-for-native-code

Answer (score 0):

Define a java interface that represents your DLL API and provide two implementations, one that calls the 32 bit DLL and another one that calls the 64 bit version:

```
public interface MyDll {
    public void myOperation();
}

public class My32BitDll implements MyDll {
    public void myOperation() {            
        // calls 32 bit DLL
    }
}

public class My64BitDll implements MyDll {
    public void myOperation() {            
        // calls 64 bit DLL
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyDll myDll = null;

        if ("32".equals(args[0])) {
            myDll = new My32BitDll();
        } else if ("64".equals(args[0])) {
            myDll = new My64BitDll();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad DLL version");
        }

        myDll.myOperation();
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt that this is what the OP wants. And it forces the user to tell the program whether it runs in a 32 bit or 64 bit environment. The program should discover that itself.