# Java classpath for 32 bit & 64 bit

Tags: java, eclipse

I have installed JDK 32 bit as well as JDK 64 bit. I have 2 eclipse installations; Helios for Android and Indigo for Java EE. Now the problem is that when I set the class path for 32 bit Indigo is not working and when I set the path for 64 bit Helios is not working.

The error I get is:

```
failed to load the jni shared library
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to load e.g. a 32 bit DLL using the 64 bit JVM, but a 32 bit JVM can only load 32 bit libraries and the other way around for a 64 bit JVM.

- You could uninstall the 32 bit eclipse version and re-install it as a 64 bit version so both programs can use the 64 bit JVM
- You can open the `eclipse.ini` and edit the `-vm` parameter to point to your correct JVM installation. So you need a 32 bit JVM installed parallel to the 64 bit JVM.

Comment: ,thanks for reply u mean i cant have 2 (32bit & 64 bit)jdk at a time ?

Comment: Correct. You can have multiple JVMs installed at the same time but only one JVM (JRE or JDK) on your system's `PATH` variable - otherwise the system would pick up the `javac` command for example only from the first directory. But eclipse allows you to specify which JVM to use when loading (-> `eclipse.ini`). So you can have your 64 bit JDK on the `PATH` and specify the path to your 32 bit JDK in the `eclipse.ini`.

Comment: thanks . good knowledge i got. 1 more ques? how to set in eclipse.ini .this is eclipse.ini i hav .    -startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.1.R36x_v20100810
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.framework.extensions=net.rim.ejde.preprocessing.hook
-Xms40m
-Xmx512M
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m

Comment: `-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_02/bin/javaw.exe` take care of the newline between `-vm` and the rest. Adjust your path for your needs.

Comment: @coding.mof:A 64-bit can not load a 32-bit DLL? Why?

Comment: That problem is not related to the OS but to the JVM. I don't know why the JVM is throwing this exception but it does. I assume that the JNI (which is used to load SWT of eclipse) doesn't detect 32 bit DLLs on a 64 bit JVM. One workaround is to [check the architecture in the Java code and load different libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449029/loading-32-or-64-bit-jni-library-in-java). But this works only if you can access the code. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't say OS. But in `Windows` the 64-bit java would install under `Program Files` while the 32-bit java under `Program Files (x86)`. If you updated the `eclipse.ini` accordingly to point to the appropriate java installation (32/64) I think you should be ok