# OSGI Bundle-NativeCode give error "No match found for native code"

Tags: java, maven, osgi, bundle, manifest

I'm developing an OSGI bundle which uses the native library **librxtxSerial**. 
The first time, I had to deploy this bundle on a raspberry, so I've did something like that:

I put the native library under: lib/librxtxSerial.so (NB: INSIDE the java project).

Then, in the MANIFEST I've wrote:

```
Bundle-NativeCode: lib/librxtxSerial.so
```

**Everything works fine!!!**

Now, the problem is that I've to deploy the same bundle on other embedded device which uses a different processor architecture (x86 instead ARM).

So, I've downloaded the x86 build for the librxtxSerial library and I modified my folder structure in something like that:

```
 - lib
   - x86
     - librxtxSerial.so
   - arm
     - librxtxSerial.so
```

And I've modified my MANIFEST in this way:

```
Bundle-NativeCode: lib/x86/librxtxSerial;processor=x86, lib/arm/librxtxSerial;processor=ARM_le
```

Trying to compile (through maven tycho plugin) I always get the same error:

```
No match found for native code: lib/x86/librxtxSerial; processor=x86, lib/arm/librxtxSerial; processor=ARM_le
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Why are you using the Tycho plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i've solved. Not sure why but in order to solve this issue is enough to add '*' at the end of the header, so:

```
Bundle-NativeCode: lib/x86/librxtxSerial;processor=x86, lib/arm/librxtxSerial;processor=ARM_le, *
```

it now works.

Comment: IIUC, the * means the bundle will still resolve even if none of the clauses match. It may be removing a symptom rather than the root issue. One thing to try: examine the value of system property `osgi.arch` in the running application, on each architecture. Does it match the values you've specified for `processor` above?